# SAS Enterprise: Compute column by comparing values

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have a dataset which broadly speaking looks like this:

```
╔════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ TICKER ║   DAY    ║   TIME   ║
╠════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ AET    ║ 20100104 ║ 09:30:04 ║
║ AET    ║ 20100104 ║ 09:30:04 ║
║ AET    ║ 20100104 ║ 09:30:04 ║
║ AET    ║ 20100104 ║ 09:30:05 ║
║ AET    ║ 20100104 ║ 09:30:05 ║
║ AET    ║ 20100104 ║ 09:30:06 ║
║ AET    ║ 20100104 ║ 09:30:06 ║
║ AET    ║ 20100104 ║ 09:30:06 ║
╚════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

I want an extra column added which represents a value of 0 in case it's not the last observation of that time and a 1 in case it's the last observation of that time. Therefore I want to add add the following column:

```
╔════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║ TICKER ║   DAY    ║   TIME   ║ dummy ║
╠════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ AET    ║ 20100104 ║ 09:30:04 ║     0 ║
║ AET    ║ 20100104 ║ 09:30:04 ║     0 ║
║ AET    ║ 20100104 ║ 09:30:04 ║     1 ║
║ AET    ║ 20100104 ║ 09:30:05 ║     0 ║
║ AET    ║ 20100104 ║ 09:30:05 ║     1 ║
║ AET    ║ 20100104 ║ 09:30:06 ║     0 ║
║ AET    ║ 20100104 ║ 09:30:06 ║     0 ║
║ AET    ║ 20100104 ║ 09:30:06 ║     1 ║
╚════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

I'm usying SAS Enterprise Guide, but don't know how to compare a value of row 1 with a value of row 2. What I'm basically trying to do is create an expression that looks like this:

```
IF TIME = TIME(row+1)
THEN 0
ELSE 1
```

I don't know if this is even possible in SAS enterprise. I'm totally new to this, and I would have no problem do such a thing in Excel. Excel just doesn't cope well with 17 million rows of data. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `last.` function here. This can be used as long as the the data is sorted appropriately (e.g. below it will need to be sorted by TICKER, DAY and TIME)

```
data new;
  set original;
  by TICKER DAY TIME;
  if last.TIME then dummy = '1';
run;
```

(If it is not then you will need to do a proc sort, however from the sample data you posted it was already)

Edit: Thanks @Joe

Comment: It would need to be `by ticker day time;` more than likely.  Then you could do `dummy=last.time;` and get your 0/1 directly.

Comment: This looks awesome. I already read about the last. function but I couldn't get it to work. My data was automatically sorted by ticker day time, but I'll try to compute this first thing tomorrow! You guys are amazing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather crude way of going about it, but it does work... I'm not 100% sure if there is a function for this but this is what I came up with quickly...

```
//Create index of each obs.
DATA DATE_TIME_TABLE;
SET DATE_TIME_TABLE;
   COLUMN INDEX;
   INDEX=_N_;
   OUTPUT;
RUN;

//Sort by descending index for each time. Last obs of each time now is first.
PROC SORT DATA=DATE_TIME;
BY TIME DESCENDING INDEX;
RUN;

//The first obs = 1 everything else = 0
DATA DATE_TIME_TABLE;
SET DATE_TIME_TABLE;
   IF TIME <> LAG(TIME) THEN
      dummy = 1;
   ELSE dummy = 0;
   END;
RUN;

//Put the table back to how it was
PROC SORT DATA=DATE_TIME_TABLE;
BY INDEX;
RUN;
```